# Use S3 getObject data as video source

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

When I request a video using Node with the AWS SDK, this is what's returned:

```
{
  AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  LastModified: 2020-08-04T17:15:34.000Z,
  ContentLength: 6480325,
  ETag: '"c52e2d08feef01b4ce3ff2a4c6adb65b"',
  ContentType: 'video/mp4',
  Metadata: {},
  Body: <Buffer 00 00 00 20 66 74 79 70 69 73 6f 6d 00 00 02 00 69 73 6f 6d 69 73 6f 32 61 76 63 31 6d 70 34 31 00 01 14 3e 6d 6f 6f 76 00 00 00 6c 6d 76 68 64 00 00 ... 6480275 more bytes>
}
```

The buffer is an `ArrayBuffer`. I'm assuming this is what I need to use as a video source but I really have no idea.

I've tried converting it to an ordinary `Buffer` and `base64` but I don't have much experience with either and neither of them worked. I was able to display the first frame of the video as an image using `base64` but not as a video.

Is there a way to do this?

Request code:

```
s3.getObject(
    {
        Bucket: "my-bucket-name",
        Key: req.body.file
    },
    (err, data) => {
        console.log(data)
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Silly mistake. The `base64` way does work, I just forgot to add the `controls` property to the video element.

Here's the code for anyone interested:

```
s3.getObject(
    {
        Bucket: "my-bucket-name",
        Key: req.body.file
    },
    (err, data) => {
        const base = new Buffer.from(data.Body.buffer).toString("base64");

        if (err)
            return res
                .status(400)
                .json({ msg: "Unable to fetch video", error: err });
        else
            return res.json({
                msg: "Video fetched",
                source: base
            });
     }
);
```

Then format on the frontend and set the video source however you want:

```
// Response from an Axios request
"data:video/mp4;base64, " + res.data.source
```